# Adding averages to a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table

```
| Location | Unit | ...
+----------|------+----
| A        | 1    | ...
| A        | 1    | ...
| B        | 1    | ...
| A        | 2    | ...
| C        | 2    | ...
| ...      | ...  | ...
```

and I want to compute a new table with the 'average' location value for each unit, in the following sense:

```
| Location | Unit | Weight |
+----------|------+--------+
| A        | 1    | 0.6667 |
| B        | 1    | 0.3333 |
| A        | 2    | 0.5    |
| C        | 2    | 0.5    |
| ...      | ...  | ...    |
```

Of course it is simple enough to get the totals

```
select unit, location, count(*)
from table1
group by unit, location;
```

and to create the table

```
create table table2 (Unit nvarchar(50), Location int, Weight float);
```

but I'm not sure how to populate it with the average data. (This isn't hard, but somehow I'm stuck... it's been many years since I worked on SQL Server.)

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776381%28v=sql.105%29.aspx#BulkLoad

Comment: can you enlight me how do you get average location values here? and you name them Weight?

Comment: When you say average, do you mean distinct? There's an AVG() function, but you couldn't use it on varchar data. Are you just looking to insert from your query into table2?

Comment: Can you provide more info? Your naming convention is such that it makes me wonder if unit is a segregation of location types, or a count of units (to be measured) within that specific location. If it is the latter then you will need to multiply the weight (which again we need more info on) against that unit and then get a average based on grouping and possibly the sum() of the units?

Comment: @Talspaugh27: Look at all cases with Unit 1. The locations are A, A, and B. A appears two out of three times, for a total weight of 2/3. B appears once out of three times, for a weight of 1/3. Similarly unit 2 appears twice, once in location A and once in C, for a total weight of 1/2 in each.

Comment: @april4181: I don't know what you mean by distinct here. I want to look at all the (unit, location) pairs and give the number of times it appears out of the total number of times the unit appears.

Comment: @skobaljic: Do the last two comments clear this up for you? If not I'll see if I can explain it differently.

Comment: Thanks, you can instead edit your question and make it clear for future visitors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd use `COUNT OVER` for this:

```
select distinct
  location, unit, 
  cast(count(*) over (partition by unit, location) as decimal) / 
  cast(count(*) over (partition by unit) as decimal) as weight
from mytable
order by unit, location;
```

#### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2b26b/5)

Comment: This answer does what I need, and also makes me feel better that it wasn't *that* simple of a thing I was missing. Thanks for getting me unstuck!

Answer (score 2):

You want to do a weighted average, with units as the weight.  You need both the sum for each location/unit combination and the total for each `location`.  To produce your output:

```
select location, unit, (1.0*unit) / sum(unit) over (partition by location)
from table1
group by location, unit;
```

The `1.0*` is just a fast way of converting to a decimal value, in the event that `unit` is actually an integer.

EDIT:

If you just want the counts, then this should work:

```
select location, unit, count(*) as cnt,
       (1.0*count(*)) / sum(count(*)) over (partition by unit)
from table1
group by location, unit;
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't explain this well enough, but "unit" is just a name. I don't want to average Unit 1 and Unit 2 to come up with a fictitious Unit 1.5. In my example, unit 1 appears 3 times, twice with location A and once with location B, so the weight should be 2/3 for A and 1/3 for B. Unit 2 appears once each with locations A and C so these have weight 1/2 each.

Answer (score 0):

While you haven't said that there is a weight column, I'm assuming there must be (otherwise, what do you mean by weight?)

```
select unit, location, AVG(weight)
from table1
group by unit, location;
```

as the select statement

```
select unit, location, AVG(weight)
into table2
from table1
group by unit, location;
```

as an insert into a new table

Comment: There is no weight column in `table1`. In my example, unit 1 appears 3 times, twice with location A and once with location B, so the weight should be 2/3 for A and 1/3 for B. Unit 2 appears once each with locations A and C so these have weight 1/2 each.